# Copying fields of layer without going to attribute table

Tags: qgis

I would like to automatically copy (without going to copy in the attribute table) all the fields and their data, from layer 1 to paste them into layer 2.

Do I have to go through a python program copying the data from the layer 1 to layer 2 or do you know a keyboard shortcut allowing it?

[image: Picture layer]

Comment: **copy** all objects from `layer1` and **paste** into `layer2` : does it fit your needs ? that's quite quick ...

Comment: I want to copy all objects without enter in the attribut table. I want to find programme or a shortcut for people doesn't know QGIS.

Comment: do you mean all attributes of one feature in layer1 to one feature in layer2? Then you can use a plugin called 'attributepainter'.  Or do you just want to copy features from one layer to the other?  then just Ctrl + C and Ctrl + v

Comment: Yes, i want just copy features like Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v. I test attibutepainter but, i didn't anderstand it work.

Comment: Rectification, i know how to use attribute painter, but i don't create a new feature. So it can't solve my problematic. :(